# CSS Flex property not working with my React Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm working with a React project that requires me to use Flex in my styling. All have done is just not working have used almost all the flex property and yet it seems not to be working. My expected output is the image below[image]

But this is what I'm getting below
[image]

Also, my Barchart Component is this

```
import React from "react";
const tenHighestPopulation = [
  { country: "World", population: 7693165599, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "China", population: 1377422166, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "India", population: 1295210000, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "USA", population: 323947000, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Indonesia", population: 258705000, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Brazil", population: 206135893, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Pakistan", population: 194125062, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Nigeria", population: 186988000, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Bangladesh", population: 161006790, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Russian", population: 146599183, percentage: 0 },
  { country: "Japan", population: 126960000, percentage: 0 },
];
export default function Bargroup() {

  for (var i = 0; i < tenHighestPopulation.length; i++) {
    const max = Math.max.apply(
      Math,
      tenHighestPopulation.map(function (o) {
        return o.population;
      })
    );
    // console.log(max);
    // we do the conversion here
    tenHighestPopulation[i].percentage =
      Math.round((tenHighestPopulation[i].population / max) * 100) + "%";
  }

  return (
    <div className="percent" >
      {tenHighestPopulation.map((countries, index) => (
        <div key={index}  className="details">
          <div className="country"> {countries.country}</div>
       <div className="content"  style={{
              backgroundColor: "yellow",
              width: `${countries.percentage}`,
            }}></div> 
          <div className="population"> {countries.population}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my style sheet is this

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
   
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center; */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

.background_div{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
.hexa_center{
    padding-top: 40px; 
}


.percent{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;


}

.details{
 display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;   
margin: 10px;
   
   }
   .country{
    
   }
   .content{
    
   }
   .population{
    
   }
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Numbers from "./Numbers";
import Hexa from "./Hexa";
import "./Style.css";
import Bargroup from "./Bargroup";

export default function App() {
  // const numbers = [1]

  const numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
    }
  }

  const hexaColor = () => {
    let str = "0123456789abcdef";
    let color = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length);
      color += str[index];
    }
    return "#" + color;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="child">
        <div className="child_content">
          <h1> React</h1>
          <h2></h2>
        </div>
        <div className="ul">
          <ul>
            <Numbers className="block" numbers={numbers} />
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="child_content">
          <h1> React</h1>
          <h2> Colors</h2>
        </div>
        {new Array(32).fill(0).map((item, i) => {
          return <Hexa key={i} hexaColor={hexaColor} className="block" />;
        })}

        <div className="child_content">
          <h1> React</h1>
          <h2> Population</h2>
          <h3>Ten Most Populated Countries</h3>
          <Bargroup />
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see your imported sheet in main file.
Under:

```
import React from "react";
```

Put:

```
import './pathToYourCss.css';
```

Comment: It was in my App.js that I'm importing the style,css @matt_dablu

Comment: I see. Importing that in your component does not work?

Comment: Importing it in my App.js worked since I'm passing my bar group component inside the same App.js and the image of the result I'm getting is above.

Comment: I just updated the code, I included my App.js @matt_dablu

Comment: Ok I can see there is some extra components which are not included in code you provided. It will be a bit difficult to try solve the problem and get expected result without them, however I will ask you again. Did you try to import those css files to your component? BTW: having all css in one main file it is also bad practice and Reacts idea with components it is that allows you to keep everything seperate for different components to avoid mess. Once again please try to seperate your css selectors just for this component and import them to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much the list that needs to be in a flex box (column), but the list item:

`display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; .details, .population: flex-shrink: 0; content-wrapper: flex-grow: 2;`

This should get you close. Cheers

Comment: You could nest `.content` inside a `.content-wrapper` with a `flex-grow: 2`.

There are other options of course. Check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for the count element:

```css
Flex: 1;
Justify-self: end;
```